# Trigger Event for Shapes that change layer on Visio VBA

Tags: vba, visio

I want to stylize the shapes the first time it goes in a different layer but only ONCE. (Example: The Shape will change color when it goes in the Visible layer for the first time) Is there any event I can use that triggers every time a Shape is moved from one layer to another?

I've tried using CellChanged, ShapeChanged, and FormulaChanged with the target vsoShape but it didn't seem to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: "didn't seem to work" is a rather vague description of what the problem is. If there is no event that fires given *exactly* the conditions you need, then you need to use an event that fires in the next-closest scenario, and then in that event handler you determine whether your conditions are met - if that means caching shapes' layer and comparing to a modified shape's current layer, then you need to implement that. Does `ShapeChanged` fire when you move a shape from one layer to another?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I've used ShapeChanged Private Sub but it didn't change the shape's format. The closest I can get is CellChanged, hoping that I can find the properties from the Shapesheet to directly call out the layers. (For example, If this shape's layer cell changes value, then fill color etc.) But it doesn't look like there's any property I can use from Shapesheet sadly.